# Odoo 8 or later - Filter calendar events

Tags: odoo-8, odoo-10

I'd like to filter a list of events.
In Odoo, an event has a field "Partner_ids" to add attendees.
In my table "res_partner", i added a field "ContactType".

I'd like to display the events only with attendees to a certain "ContactType", but i don't find how to write my domain to achieve this.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do . But if you want filter event in the view calendar you can use the filter.

You must create a new filter in the search view for your new field (in this case is ContactType).

```
<search>
    <filter name="Type seller" string="Seller" domain="[('ContactType', '=', 'seller')]"/>
</search>
```

Comment: I will ty to be more precise.

To simplify my research, i can say "i'm trying to make three filters to display :
- All the events,
- Or the events with customer attendees,
- Or the events with supplier attendees.

It seems a bit difficult to do.

Comment: You need create 3 filters:

1 : <filter name="seller_type" string="Seller type" domain="[('ContactType', '=', 'seller')]"/>

2 : <filter name="customer_type" string="Customer type" domain="[('ContactType', '=', 'customer')]"/>

3  =<filter name="all_type" string="All type" domain="['|',('ContactType', '=', 'seller'),('ContactType', '=', 'customer')]"/>

Comment: No it doesn't work beacause the field "ContactType" isn't in the event table but in the res_partner table.

Comment: You can inherit your event model and added a related field ContactType from your partner